# How to keep line's source commit reference while changing its indentation

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

Having a simple code added in commit `111111`:

```
showHappyIcon();
```

And developing it in commit `222222` like:

```
if(config.IconsEnabled) {
  showHappyIcon();
}
```

results in line with `showHappyIcon();` being linked to commit `222222` while using git blame. Only white space characters has been added, but it seems it's enough for git to treat is as new line.

I want to have `showHappyIcon();`'s line been referenced to commit `111111` while keeping the new indentation in the code. Is there a good way to implement it?

Comment: Two recommendations.  First, try adding the `-w` option on the command line for `git blame`.  This will tell it to ignore changes in whitespace and provides a better opportunity for git to assign the line to the correct revision.  Second, it to perhaps try setting the diff algorithm to "patience".  I do this through my gitconfig, as it generates diffs that better represent my intention.  The only catch here is that I'm not sure if it affects `git blame` output or not, but I suspect it does.

Comment: As john is saying, you are doing the right thing: adjusting indentation of the file. Do not stop doing it. Hate it when people do not indent appropriately. Then use `-w`  if you need to see through the spacing changes.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister the `-w` parameter is exactly what I need. Please post an answer and I will mark it as a solution. Additional question, do you know if this could be used in bitbucket code comparison?

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to say "ignore whitespace" when annotating via the web browser on Bitbucket.  You do have the option when viewing a diff though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two recommendations. First, try adding the `-w` option on the command line for `git blame`. This will tell it to ignore changes in whitespace and provides a better opportunity for git to assign the line to the correct revision. Second, it to perhaps try setting the diff algorithm to "patience". I do this through my gitconfig, as it generates diffs that better represent my intention. The only catch here is that I'm not sure if it affects git blame output or not, but I suspect it does.